# Recursively read files from remote server present in subdirectories with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I have working flow for getting files from single folder present in remote server using inbound adopter but i want for get files for all subfolder present in any remote server parent folder
I have code like this

```
 @Bean
    public SessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser("foo");
        factory.setPassword("foo");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        factory.setTestSession(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }
@Bean
public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("foo");
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    source.setMaxFetchSize(1);
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println(message.getPayload());
        }

    };
}`
```

but instead of single folder i want get files for all subfolder present in foo directory

if possible please help with full code

@GaryRussell
Thanks you so much for you early response .I have done some changes according to your suggested code app is started but files is not getting picked up by application.

```
    CompositeFileListFilter<LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter fileListFilter =
        new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(
            (JdbcMetadataStore) context.getBean("metadataStore"), "REMOTE");
    if (Constants.APP1.equals(appName) || Constants.APP2.equals(appName)) {
      SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter regexPatternFileListFilter =
          new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(Pattern.compile("^IL.*"));
      compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(regexPatternFileListFilter);
    }
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(fileListFilter);
 return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(
            () -> sftpEnvironment.getSftpGLSIncomingDir(), // remote dir
            e -> e.autoStartup(true).poller(pollerMetada()))
        .handle(
            Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), Command.MGET, "payload")
                .options(Option.RECURSIVE)
                .filter(compositeFileListFilter)
                .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.IGNORE)
                .localDirectoryExpression("'/tmp/' + #remoteDirectory")) // re-create tree locally
        .split()
        .log()
        .get();
```

@GaryRussell
I have changed my code this new way it is partially processing files mean one example out of 10 file only process 5 or 6 files. I am not able to figure the main issue in that.and I also have also some open challenges which i am mentioning below

- Its able to read files form remote subdirectories and store in local directory but I want to process these file in some other sftpChannel, if posible without storing locally
- I also want to apply some deduplication technique using data base which will help me to avoid duplicate file processing.

```java
public class SFTPPollerService {


  @Bean
  public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    //code
    return factory;
  }


//OLD code 
  //    @Bean
  //    public SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
  //        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer =
  //                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
  //        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(sftpEnvironment.isDeleteRemoteFiles());
  //        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(sftpEnvironment.getSftpGLSIncomingDir());
  //        fileSynchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
  //        CompositeFileListFilter<LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new
  // CompositeFileListFilter<>();
  //        SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter fileListFilter =
  //                new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(
  //                        (JdbcMetadataStore) context.getBean("metadataStore"), "REMOTE");
  //        if (Constants.app2.equals(appName)
  //                || Constants.app1.equals(appName)) {
  //            SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter regexPatternFileListFilter =
  //                    new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(Pattern.compile("*.txt"));
  //            compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(regexPatternFileListFilter);
  //        }
  //        compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(fileListFilter);
  //        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(compositeFileListFilter);
  //        return fileSynchronizer;
  //    }
  //
  //    @Bean
  //    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller("pollerMetada"))
  //    public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource() {
  //        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
  //                new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
  //        source.setLocalDirectory(new File(sftpEnvironment.getSftpLocalDir()));
  //
  //        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
  //
//          try {
//              source.setLocalFilter(
//                      (FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter)
//                              context.getBean("filelistFilter"));
//          } catch (Exception e) {
//              LOG.error(
//                      "Exception caught while setting local filter on
//   SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource",
//                      e);
//          }
  //        source.setMaxFetchSize(sftpEnvironment.getMaxFetchFileSize());
  //
  //        return source;
  //    }


//new Code 
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {

    CompositeFileListFilter<LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter fileListFilter =
        new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(
            (JdbcMetadataStore) context.getBean("metadataStore"), "REMOTE");
    if (Constants.app2.equals(appName) || Constants.app1.equals(appName)) {
      SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter regexPatternFileListFilter =
          new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(Pattern.compile("(subDir | *.txt)"));

      compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(regexPatternFileListFilter);
    }

    fileListFilter.setForRecursion(true);
    FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter fileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter = (FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter) context.getBean(
        "filelistFilter");
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilter(fileListFilter);




//    IntegrationFlow ir =
//        IntegrationFlows.from(
//                Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory())
//                    .preserveTimestamp(true)
//                    .remoteDirectory(sftpEnvironment.getSftpGLSIncomingDir())
//                    .deleteRemoteFiles(sftpEnvironment.isDeleteRemoteFiles())
//                    .filter(compositeFileListFilter)
//                    .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
//                    .localDirectory(new File(sftpEnvironment.getSftpLocalDir())),
//                e -> e.autoStartup(true).poller(pollerMetada()))
//            .handle(handler())
//            .get();

    return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(
            () -> sftpEnvironment.getSftpGLSIncomingDir(), // remote dir
            e -> e.autoStartup(true).poller(pollerMetada()))
        .handle(
            Sftp.outboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), Command.MGET, "payload")
                .options(Option.RECURSIVE)
                .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.IGNORE)
                .regexFileNameFilter("(dsv[0-9]|.*.xml)")

                //                .filter(compositeFileListFilter)
                .localDirectoryExpression("'user/localDir/test/'"))
        //        .handle(handler())
        // .patternFileNameFilter(".*\\.xml")) // re-create tree locally
        .split()
        .channel("sftpChannel")
        // .handle(handler())
        .log()
        .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public PollerMetadata pollerMetada() {
    PollerMetadata pm = new PollerMetadata();
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor processor =
        new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("payload.delete()");
    processor.setAfterRollbackExpression(exp);
    TransactionSynchronizationFactory tsf = new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(processor);
    pm.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(tsf);
    List<Advice> advices = new ArrayList<>();
    advices.add(compoundTriggerAdvice());
    pm.setAdviceChain(advices);
    pm.setTrigger(compoundTrigger());
    pm.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(sftpEnvironment.getMaxMessagesPerPoll());

    return pm;
  }

  @Bean
  public CronTrigger cronTrigger() {
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
      return new CronTrigger(sftpEnvironment.getPollerCronExpressionWhenDebugModeIsEnabled());
    } else {
      return new CronTrigger(sftpEnvironment.getPollerCronExpression());
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public PeriodicTrigger periodicTrigger() {
    return new PeriodicTrigger(sftpEnvironment.getPeriodicTriggerInMillis());
  }

  @Bean
  public CompoundTrigger compoundTrigger() {
    return new CompoundTrigger(cronTrigger());
  }

  @Bean
  public CompoundTriggerAdvice compoundTriggerAdvice() {
    return new CompoundTriggerAdvice(compoundTrigger(), periodicTrigger());
  }

  @Bean
  public FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter filelistFilter(MetadataStore datastore) {
    return new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter((JdbcMetadataStore) datastore, "INT");
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager();
  }

  @Bean
  DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {

    OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(databaseProperties.getOracleUsername());
    dataSource.setPassword(databaseProperties.getOraclePassword());
    dataSource.setURL(databaseProperties.getOracleUrl());
    dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
    dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
    return dataSource;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a {@link JdbcMetadataStore} for the de-duplication logic.
   *
   * <p>This method uses the "REGION" column of the metadatastore table to differentiate between
   * multiple apps. The value of the "REGION" column is set equal to the app-name.
   *
   * @return a JDBC metadata store
   * @throws SQLException in case an exception occurs during connection to SQL database
   */
  @Bean
  public MetadataStore metadataStore() throws SQLException {
    JdbcMetadataStore jdbcMetadataStore = new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource());

  
    if (!Constants.app2.equals(appName)) {
      jdbcMetadataStore.setRegion(appName);
    }

    return jdbcMetadataStore;
  }

  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
  public MessageHandler handler() {
    return message -> {
      File file = (File) message.getPayload();
    
      FileDto fileDto = new FileDto(file);
      fileHandler.handle(fileDto);
      LOG.info("controller is here ");
      try {
        if (sftpEnvironment.isDeleteLocalFiles()) {
          Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(file.toString()));
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO retry/report/handle gracefully
        LOG.error(String.format("MessageHandler had error message=%s", message), e);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: @gary-russell I have gone through this documentation but not able to related my code with given examples in spring document , can u give me some running  example for this problem 

-- _Instead of synchronizer how we can replace with outbound gateway_.

Comment: There are examples in the documentation I referenced, but I'll add another to the answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell
I have done some edit can u check what is problem with is code

Comment: It is hard to tell from static code - run it in a debugger to see why you aren't getting files.

Comment: Note that the subdirectory names must pass the filter, as described in the docs; your regex seems quite restrictive. See `setForRecursion()` on the filter.

Comment: @GaryRussell. I have  pass simple regex its is working but in my case we need this composite filler so how can we use this composite filter ,when i am passing regex into this i am getting this error 'File name pattern must be '*' when using recursion'

--I also want to pass this payload into one message handler so that i can process these files further

Comment: See my example; the result of the expression (`payload` in my case) must look like `<directory>/*`; this has nothing to do with the filter, which is applied after the results are retrieved; the regex filter must be configured for use with recursion.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have able to get files from remote server and then i am passing this payload to another channel for processing these file but  when files get pulled then only some files are getting processed with this processor channel
how we can resolve this issue so that  we can process all files which are coming from remote to local and i also want some deduplication in my repo using data source. can u guild me to how we can do that

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; ask a new question showing your current code and a more detailed explanation of the problem.

Comment: @GaryRussell Okay sir I have added my current code here. Can u please help me to resolve my current issues and challenges

Answer (score 0):

The synchronizer doesn't support recursion. Use the outbound gateway with a recursive `mget` command instead.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

> Using the mget Command
> mget retrieves multiple remote files based on a pattern and supports the following options:

> -P: Preserve the timestamps of the remote files.

> -R: Retrieve the entire directory tree recursively.

> -x: Throw an exception if no files match the pattern (otherwise, an empty list is returned).

> -D: Delete each remote file after successful transfer. If the transfer is ignored, the remote file is not deleted, because the FileExistsMode is IGNORE and the local file already exists.

> The message payload resulting from an mget operation is a `List<File>` object (that is, a List of `File` objects, each representing a retrieved file).

**EDIT**

Here is an example using the java DSL...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75180789Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75180789Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf) {
        return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(() -> "foo/*", // remote dir
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sf, Command.MGET, "payload")
                        .options(Option.RECURSIVE)
                        .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.IGNORE)
                        .localDirectoryExpression("'/tmp/' + #remoteDirectory")) // re-create tree locally
                .split()
                .log()
                .get();

    }

    @Bean
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf(@Value("${host}") String host,
            @Value("${username}") String user, @Value("${pw}") String pw) {

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(host);
        sf.setUser(user);
        sf.setPassword(pw);
        sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return sf;
    }

}
```

Comment: [@Gary Russell]  Thanks you so much for you early response .I have done some changes according to your suggested code app is started but files is not getting picked up by application.

'